# Make Eigenvalues in the left half plane (Complex domain analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

For a matrix $A$, its dimension is $N$ * $N (N=1,2,...)$.

The characteristic equation of the matrix A is:

$(x^2+a_2 x+a_1)^N-(a_3 x+a_1)^N-k x (x^2+a_2 x+a_1)^{(N-1)}=0$,

where $x$ is the eigenvalue, and $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ are pre-defined parameters. $a_2^2-a_3^2-2 a_1<0, a_1>0, a_2>a_3>0$.

If $\frac{-a_2\pm\sqrt{a_2^2-4 a_1}}{2}$ is not equal to $\frac{-a_1}{a_3}$, then they are not the eigenvalues, and the characteristic equation can be divided by $(x^2+a_2 x+a_1)^N$, and then the following equation can be obtained.

$1-{(\frac{a_3 x+a_1}{x^2+a_2 x+a_1})}^N-\frac{k x}{x^2+a_2 x+a_1}= 0$

**Problem**:

$k$ is nonpositive real number. What I want to do is to detemine $k$ to make all the eigenvalues have non-positive real parts. Can we find a condition or kind of approximation between $k$ and $N$, $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$?

Comment: Note that there is no need for an "if": that second equation characterizes any eigenvalues except for those two possibilities. But it doesn't really help all that much to recast it in terms of rational functions like that.

Comment: Anyway, your observation that $|a_3x + a_1|>|x^2+a_2x+a_1|$ on the imaginary axis suggests the possibility of setting this up with Rouche's theorem...but the difficulty is that Rouche's theorem requires a bounded domain, so you would need to "fill up" one half plane or the other with a family of bounded domains.)

Comment: Actually, are you sure about that conclusion? Surely as you go to say $+i\infty$ the denominator grows faster than the numerator? Seems like there must be some typo.

Comment: Yeah there is something seriously wrong with what you said there, for example with all three $a_i=1$ your condition holds, but $\left | \frac{ix+1}{-x^2+ix+1} \right |$ does not stay on the same side of $1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry, I did make a mistake in describing this problem. $a_2^2-a_3^2-2 a_1<0$ can not guarantee that for all the imaginary axis points, the module $ \frac {a_3 x+a_1}{x^2+a_2 x+a_1}$ is always larger than 1. Apologize and thanks for correcting.
Actually, the condition for parameters $a_1, a_2, a_3$ is obtained from frequency analysis and Maximum-modulus theorem for the plant analysis. This condition still holds.

Comment: What condition are you saying actually does hold? $\left | \frac{a_3x+a_1}{x^2+a_2x+a_1} \right |>1$ cannot hold on the entire imaginary axis regardless of any assumption. Are you just saying $a_2^2-a_3^2-2a_1<0$ still holds?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. What I am trying to say is $ a_2^2-a_3^2-2 a_1<0$ holds.

Comment: In this problem, the parameters restrict to inequalities: $ a_1>0, a_2>a_3>0, a_2^2-a_3^2-2 a_1>0$.

Comment: OK. Well, if you can find a family of domains say $K_n$ such that the union of the $K_n$ is the left half plane and for all $K_n$ you have $|(z^2+a_2z+a_1)^N-kz(z^2+a_2z+a_1)^{N-1}|>|a_3z+a_1|^N$ for $z \in \partial K_n$, then you're good. I do immediately see a difficulty in that $z=0$ doesn't satisfy this condition, so you'll need to approach $z=0$ instead of including it the whole time.

Comment: A different possibility: if the middle term weren't there, then the root would be the roots of $x^2+a_2 x + a_1$ together with the roots of $x^2+(a_2-k)x+a_1$. Since $a_1>0$ and $a_2>0$ and $k \leq 0$, those all have negative real part. Try to draw a domain in the left half plane containing all four of these numbers so that the boundary is far enough away from the zeros and from the origin that you can use Rouche's theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much, lan. I tried and found that Rouche's theorem can provide a way of dealing with this problem. Many thanks.

Comment: I would be interested to see you explain the details in an answer.

Comment: It can be seen that the required k decrease (absolute k increase) with N. If N->infinity, the roots approximately converge to $0$, $\frac{-a_2\pm\sqrt{a_2^2-4 a_1}}{2}$, $\frac{-a_2+k\sqrt{(a_2-k)^2-4 a_1}}{2}$. I tried to construct one or two non-interseted closed circles including these 3 roots ($0$  is not included) in the left-half plane, and then utilize Rouche's theorem to obtain the condition of k,  guaranteeing $|(z^2+a_2 z+a_1)^N−k z (z^2+a_2 z+a_1)^{(N-1)}|>|a_3 z+a_1|^N $ on the circle edge.

Comment: While this approximation is completely determined by the constructed domain, and the obtained condition of k is sufficient but non-necessary conditions for the original problem (all the roots are nonpositive required in the original problem). So the result from Rouche's theorem here is more like to obtain k with a predefined domain of roots.